# bazel build tensorflow_serving/... no such package 'inception'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to build tensorfolw_serving on OSX El Capitan and keep getting an error. I installed Bazel through homebrew.

Here is the error:

```
$ bazel build tensorflow_serving/...
Extracting Bazel installation...
............
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_robertgrzesik/fb4fbbbabd0582fe8f5abe6ab13dbfd9/external/inception_model/inception/slim/BUILD:93:1: no such package 'inception': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '@inception_model//inception/slim:slim'.
ERROR: Loading failed; build aborted.
INFO: Elapsed time: 45.554s
```

I also tried giving it the package path on my system and got a different error:

```
$ bazel build --package_path /Users/robertgrzesik/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages tensorflow_serving/...
ERROR: no targets found beneath 'tensorflow_serving'.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.131s
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Bazel through the download off their website and worked properly.

Here's a link: http://bazel.io/docs/install.html

Seems that installing from homebrew causes some errors.

Answer (score 0):

use cd.. and run this script out of tensorflow folder